# How to implement account query in FIX protocol

Tags: fix-protocol

How can I implement a FIX message to inquiry an account's balance?
Is the CollateralInquiry is for that purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Are you designing a client, or server, or both?

Comment: I'm the server-side but i also should consider the client-side..

Comment: It's an important detail for your question.  If you were client-side, I'd tell you "check their specs".  But as a server, you have to invent and document the interface that the clients must obey.  (I'm sorry, I'm not sure which message type is appropriate, as I've not worked with an interface that has such a feature.)